# How to install a module on Python?

Tags: python, shell, module, installation, pip

Okay, so, I'm actually a beginner in programming Python, and I only found out yesterday how you were supposed to encode `pip install ModuleName` in the Python command line and not in the interactive shell. I'm trying to download a lot of modules, such as the Send2Trash module, Pyperclip, Requests, Beautiful Soup, and Selenium.

Before I checked the forums about installing modules, I found out how we needed to have the pip tool. I'm a Windows user, but for some reason, I didn't have the 'Scripts' folder installed when I downloaded Python. I didn't know we needed it, so I used raw scripts from GitHub, setup.py, and copy pasted the script into the File Editor in Python, ran it in the interactive shell, and tried to import the module I needed. It worked for the Pyperclip and the Requests module; no errors popped up after I imported them using `import pyperclip` or `import requests`, but when I tried the same procedure for the rest of the modules I needed, there were some errors.

Also, when I tried to download the modules on pypi.python.org, I tried to open it using the interactive shell, but then something pops up, 'The file's encoding is invalid for Python3.x...', and when I click 'OK', it's going to say 'Failed to Decode', and close everything.

So, after reading forum after forum, I found out how to download pip, and was also able to download setuptools and wheel. I'm not sure if it's *really* already downloaded, but I was able to get the 'Scripts' folder that wasn't there before, so I guess so. I also already went into my `PATH` using the edit environment for your account thing, and I edited the `Path` variable so its value would lead to my 'Scripts' folder. Please do tell me if I did the right thing here.

So, following the advice of the forums, I tried to install the modules I needed by typing `pip install ModuleName` in the Python command line instead of the interactive shell, but it still gave me a Syntax Error. I also tried it in Command Prompt, typing the same code `pip install ModuleName`, but when I clicked Enter, nothing happens; no errors or anything. It seemed like my install was accepted, but when I tried importing the module in the interactive shell, it still gave an Import Error.

Please tell me what I did wrong throughout my process, and how to properly install the modules I need. I would include pictures into this, but it seems I can only add two before my reputation becomes 10, and I'm pretty new here, so... If there's anything I need to elaborate on about my problem, don't hesitate to ask, and I'll try my best.

Comment: If it gave you a `SyntaxError`, you typed it into the interactive shell. `pip install modulename` is not Python syntax, it is command line terminal syntax. Enter it at your _system's_ command line, such as cmd.exe or Powershell or Terminal.

Comment: Is there a pip.exe in your Scripts folder! (C:\PythonXY\Scripts )

Comment: I did type it into Command Prompt, my system's command line. In fact, I used all three-- Powershell, Command Prompt, and the Python command line.

Comment: Yes, there is a pip.exe in my 'Scripts' folder.

Answer (score 1):

You say you use windows so you need to understand pip.
pip is a program that installs python modules. You can even use *easy_install* instead of pip.
some pip commands

`pip list` -- lists out already installed modules.

`pip search <module name>` -- searches new modules.

`pip -h` -- more pip commands you want.

pip installs modules from CMD prompt **not from** python shell.

Even after installing modules some modules doesn't run as `import module`
they need to be imported as `from module import function`.

refer the pip help command and install modules.

**DO NOT SAVE SCRIPT FILES IN PYTHON ROOT FOLDER YOU MAY FACE SOME PROBLEMS**

**Happy Programming!!!**

Answer (score 0):

After a whole lot of searching and trying out, I found the solution to my problem. For future Python users who encounter the same thing: **always install your modules in the root folder.**

In my case, my Command Prompt was automatically inside the `C:\Users` folder, which caused some problems because I couldn't download my module in there. Once I typed in `cd C:\Python34`, which was my root folder, I could successfully download the modules I needed using `pip install ModuleName`.